# Get ajax generated content from another website

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have an automated archive of several (media) websites' frontpage, written in php. Specifically, I am copying the html in the `<body>` tag twice a day, I have a copy of all their css and js files, so I can recreate the frontpage from any point in the past. Now, I came to a problem with one of those websites, as they load the main slider content (most important news) with an ajax call. I would like this ajax call to be executed before I parse the data, not just a blank div. By looking around, I found out they use a wordpress plugin named `lof-jslidernews2`, but I can't find the specific ajax call to see the url and make curl request. Any ideas how to achieve this?

The website: http://fokus.mk/

My code (had to parse manually like this, because of some problems with DomDocument and not-valid html):

```
// ...
if($html = file_get_contents ($row['page_url'])) {
    $content = strstr($html, '<body');
    $content = str_before($content, '</body>') . '</body>';
    $filename = date('YmdHis') . $row['page_name'];
    if($success = file_put_contents ('app/webroot/files/' . $filename, $content)) {
    // ....
```

** There is nothing illegal about my project, I am not stealing content, just freezing frontpages for later comparison. I have consulted a lawyer about this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but the guy that actually solved my problem deleted his answer. So, here it is:

He suggested using an emulator, specifically [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/). It was easy to install (using composer) and did the job on the first try. Awesome library.

> Mink is an open source browser controller/emulator for web applications, written in PHP 5.3.